# Make excel assume that I want to open my xlstart file readonly

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I have a workbook called Book1.xlsx in my XLSTART folder. Is there a way to tell excel that I want it to always open this file as readonly unless I specify otherwise? There are two reasons I want this.

First, I don't want to accidentally overwrite the setup that I have in the file. Second, whenever I open additional instances of excel after the first instance, I get a prompt telling me that Book1.xlsx is locked for editing.

I'm using excel 2010.

Thanks

Comment: Find the file in the XLStart folder and set it to Read-only?

Comment: Rename the file to `*.xltx`. This will flag it as a template, which Excel will automatically make a copy of in memory before opening.

Comment: Techie007, when I do that, I still get a prompt when I open excel asking if I want to open the file Read-only. Is there a way to suppress that prompt and just open it Read-only automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you rename a `*.xlsx` file to `*.xltx`, then Excel will treat it as a *template*:

- The file will be assumed to be read-only (though, it still might get locked)
- If you try to save after opening a template, Excel will prompt you to pick a new filename to save it to. You need to manually select "Excel Template" and re-choose the original template if you want to save changes to the template

---

If you want to launch Excel at BelowNormal process priority and open a file, create a `*.bat` file with the following contents:

```
start /BelowNormal <Path to Excel> <Path to file>
```

Comment: Thanks, but the main reason I am using a start up file is that I want to allow excel to use a custom number of processors for multi-threaded calculations. When I change the file to a template file, that option gets reset to using all of my processors when I close and reopen excel.

Comment: @Eric How many processors does it use by default, and how many processors are you setting it to use?

Comment: It uses all of them (32) by default, and I would like for it to use 28. The 28 is somewhat arbitrary, but I want it to use most but not all of them.

Comment: Also, I mean threads, not processors.

Comment: @Eric If you're concerned about it not sharing CPU time with other processes, launch it at `BelowNormal` priority. This will allow it to use all 32 threads if they are available, but make it back off if any other normal priority process needs CPU.

Comment: Thanks. That sounds like it will do the trick. Is there a way to set excel to run at BelowNormal priority by default?

Comment: @Eric Excel, no, but you can write a `*.bat` file that will launch Excel at BelowNormal and open the file. Would that work?